# performance issue while calling batchUpdate by java to update multiple rows on mysql 8

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc, batch-updates

I met performance issue with batchUpdate for multiple rows on mysql 8 by using java.

There are more than 400,000 rows in the table , I was trying to update a column by it's id.

The sql is like: update table_name set status='status' where id = 1.

I used batchUpdate to update 10,000 rows per time.

There is an index for the column "id", and the parameter was set to jdbcUrl too:

```
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
```

The java code is :

```java
String sql = "update table_name set status='status' where id=?";
try(Connection conn = ds.getConnection();PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){
            for(int i=0;i<idList.size();i++){
                ps.setInt(1,idList.get(i));
                ps.addBatch();
                if((i%10000==0&&i>0)||i==idList.size()-1){
                    System.out.println("now we execute from "+(i-10000)+" to "+i);
                    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    ps.executeBatch();
                    System.out.println("execute from "+(i-10000)+" to "+i+" took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-s));
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

By executing this code, I found it was very slow. It took about 60 to 90 seconds to update 10,000 records.

But when I called this code again, I found it only took 1 second to finish the job ,only if these rows were updated once.

I just wonder why the performace is so different.  Does it cause by some cache mechanism?

When the performance was poor, I checked the innodb status, and found the update operation was waiting for handler commit. So I understand why it is slow. But why it was much faster when I run it again?

The phenomenon only occurs when I am not using transaction. Once the transaction is added to the code, it always takes about 1 second.

Comment: Is there a way to get the generated query?  I want to see if `id=?` really turned into `id IN (?,?,?...)`.

Comment: No, the executions kept in the original sql query.

Comment: For speed and stability, you need to do a hundred rows in a single `UPDATE. whether that is using `IN(...)` or `BETWEEN` or `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UPDATE` must save the old copy of each row.  It tries to save it in a log file, but if that fills up, it does it in a slower way, using the actual tables.  I feel much safer doing batches of only 100 to 1000.

Also, any secondary indexes are queued up for later storing to disk.  (Don't worry, even a system crash will not lose them.)

10,000 is well into "diminishing returns", so there is no advantage in going that high.  And as mentioned above, a *potential* disadvantage.

When an `UPDATE` does not change any values, it can run faster.

To change an entire column of a table smells like a design flaw.  Perhaps a timestamp would let you discover the "status" during any subsequent `SELECT`?  This might completely eliminate the big `UPDATE`.  Or maybe the `status` can be stored in another table?